# How to poison an identifier in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, pragma, preprocessor-directive

**Function poisoning** is very useful technique in C++.

In general it refers to making a function unusable, e.g. if you want to ban the use of dynamic allocation in a program you could **"poison"** the malloc function so it can't be used. **'Poisoning'** an identifier means that any reference to the identifier after the 'poisoning' is a hard compiler error

For example (See live demo [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7oTARsuz7uT5uttb))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#pragma GCC poison malloc
int main()
{
    int* p=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));  // compiler error use of poisoned function malloc
    *p=3;
    std::cout<<*p<<'\n';
    free(p);
}
```

I found this technique very useful to prevent misuse of reserved words in C++.

For example:

```
#include "test.h"            // contains definition of some class T
#pragma GCC poison private
#define private public      // oops compiler error use of poisoned identifier private in macro
int main()
{
        // Instantiate T & use it members
}
```

This can also be used in C to prevent the use of C++ keywords because C++ has many keywords than C & it is perfectly valid to use C++ specific keywords as an identifier in C.

For example (See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/k9q1nW))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma GCC poison new
int main(void)
{
     int new=5;     // oops compiler error use of poisoned identifer new.
     printf("%d",new);
}
```

But to use this poisoning we need to use the pragma directive which is implementation defined. Fortunately the GCC pragma reconginized by clang & also works nicely. But which pragma is needed If I 've VC++ compiler (Microsoft Visual studio). How to do this in VC++ compiler?

Comment: Have you tried reading and searching Microsoft's extensive online documentation?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: yes, but didn't find my answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

MSVC++ has two ways to do this.  To get the GCC version you'd use [#pragma deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8xdzzhh.aspx).  That produces warning C4995, you can turn that into an error with /WX.

That however poisons any identifier with the name you specified, it isn't selective enough to prevent warnings on C++ members that happen to have the same identifier name.  You couldn't use it to deprecate a specific function overload for example.  Solved by the second way, [__declspec(deprecated)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/044swk7y.aspx).

In general you'd prefer the latter to avoid accidental matches.  But do beware that it has a chicken-and-egg problem, you can only deprecate a function that the compiler knows about.  Forcing you to, say, #include a header that you don't want to use at all.