# How to force the C++ compiler to warn when a specific std class function is called?

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++, utf-8, clang

I'm trying to use UTF-8 `std::string` and `std::filesystem::path` in a fool-proof way on Windows 10+ where `Beta: Use Unicode UTF-8 for worldwide language support` is likely off. C++17 or above.

To go from a `path` to a UTF-8 `string`, I have to use `path.u8string()` instead of `path.string()`.

And to go from a UTF-8 `string` to a `path`, I have to use `u8path()` instead of `path()`.

How can I make the compiler help catch me when I call the "wrong" functions? This includes implicit construction of `path`, that is:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

void foo(const std::filesystem::path& path) {}

std::string pathString; // UTF-8 string.
foo(pathString) // Wrong. path() expects native encoding.
foo(u8path(pathString)) // Make sure to always use u8path().

std::filesystem::path path;
path.string() // Wrong. Returns native encoding.
path.u8string() // Make sure to always use u8string().
```

Can I force the C++ compiler to warn me when specific functions are called? On either MSVC, GCC or Clang, preferably on all? Can I easily prevent myself from making these errors in some other way?

**Update Jan 25, 2021**

I've been able to fix my underlying issue by calling `setlocale(LC_ALL, ".UTF-8");` before any calls to `std::filesystem::path()` and `std::filesystem::path::string()`. This seems to make the MSVC standard library accept and give out strings as UTF-8 on Windows 7+ with Visual C++ 2019 ([relevant Microsoft STL issue](https://github.com/microsoft/STL/issues/909)).

After that I found [Use UTF-8 code pages in Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page) (can't believe it took me so long to find) which also makes `std::filesystem::path` work in UTF-8, but additionally also makes argv, envp and all A- Win32 API calls use UTF-8 (requires Windows 10, Version 1903).

But the initial question is still valid--how to warn or prevent the use (poison) of arbirary functions.

Comment: Are these functions implemented in header files or in a static library or shared object (DLL)?  It's relatively easy to search `objdump` output for unresolved references (because you haven't run the linker yet) to a specific name.

Comment: @Ben: Do you mean the `.string()` and `path()` functions I don't want to call? They're part of the c++17 standard library. I have full access to my own code from where I don't want to call these standard library functions.

Comment: Yes, I mean those functions.  Are they defined inside `<filesystem>` or declared there and defined inside `msvcrtxxxx.lib` or `libc++xxxx.a` ?  When the compiler runs it generates a `.obj` or `.o` file which in addition to the machine code version of your own code, lists all identifiers which the linker needs to resolve, which will include all identifiers that your program uses to call functions in the C++ standard library runtime library (static or DLL), but it won't include things defined in header files and inlined to remove the function call.

Answer (score 1):

GCC and clang have a `poison` pragma which you might find helpful here.  Unfortunately, you can only poison tokens, and not fully qualified names, so while you can do:

`#pragma GCC poison string`

you cannot do (for example):

`#pragma GCC poison std::filesystem::path::string`

Still, maybe this is something you could wrap in a `#ifdef` and enable it periodically in a test build to weed out errors in your code.

Here's a fully worked example:

```
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>

#pragma GCC poison string

int main ()
{
    std::filesystem::path path;
    auto x = path.string();         // error: attempt to use poisoned "string"
    auto y = path.u8string();       // OK
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FrTnCQcYBrI4AJhV)

Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34118209/how-to-poison-an-identifier-in-vc) for an MSVC solution.  More `#ifdef's` coming to a screen near you :)

Comment: Unfortunately also doesn't catch the implicit `path(string)` constructor, which is the easiest for a human to miss as well.

Answer (score 0):

A hacky approach I've used in similar situations in the past: Edit the system header(s) and add `[[deprecated]]` to the functions that you don't want to use.

Comment: Would love to find a solution that works across systems and compilers.

Comment: Or at least doesn't require modifying the standard library.

Comment: @milianw: Could do that on a redeclaration in your own codebase? Does that work?

Comment: @VittorioRomeo that's not easy to do selectively for a single method of a large class. i.e. you'd essentially have to copy the header from the system lib and make sure it's found before the system one.